# ASP.NET Core - Error trying to use HealthChecks

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to use the .NET Core 2.2 Health Checks.

In `ConfigureServices` I registered my class that implements the `Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.IHealthCheck` interface.

But when I execute the `UseHealthChecks` extension method inside the `Configure` method, it throws an error:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseHealthChecks("/hc"); // <-- Error in this line
    // ...
```

**System.InvalidOperationException:** 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.HealthCheckService' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.HealthCheckMiddleware'

Comment: Whenever the error is "Unable to resolve service for type...", always check the ConfigureServices function is registering the necessary things in DI ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You'll have to configure the health check infrastructure services via the `AddHealthChecks()` extension method. For example:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHealthChecks();
}
```

Also see [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-2.2#basic-health-probe).

Comment: Please see the answer from hpsanampudi. The storage provider is required. You would get a different error if you had not called AddHealthChecks

Answer (score 25):

In my case the health checks UI itself not launching and crashing the .net core 3.1 web API application.

**Error Message:**
*Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: HealthChecks.UI.Core.Notifications.IHealthCheckFailureNotifier Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: HealthChecks.UI.Core.Notifications.WebHookFailureNotifier': Unable to resolve service for type 'HealthChecks.UI.Core.Data.HealthChecksDb' while attempting to activate  'HealthChecks.UI.Core.Notifications.WebHookFailureNotifier'.)*

**Fix**: Add any [UI storage provider](https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks#Configuration) . In my case I have choosen **AddInMemoryStorage()**

**Startup.cs**

```cs
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...
        
        services.AddHealthChecks() 
            .AddDbContextCheck<PollDbContext>() //nuget: Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.EntityFrameworkCore
            .AddApplicationInsightsPublisher(); //nuget: AspNetCore.HealthChecks.Publisher.ApplicationInsights
    
        services.AddHealthChecksUI() //nuget: AspNetCore.HealthChecks.UI
            .AddInMemoryStorage(); //nuget: AspNetCore.HealthChecks.UI.InMemory.Storage
            
        ...
    }
    
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        ...
        
        app.UseHealthChecks("/healthcheck", new HealthCheckOptions
        {
            Predicate = _ => true,
            ResponseWriter = UIResponseWriter.WriteHealthCheckUIResponse //nuget: AspNetCore.HealthChecks.UI.Client
        });
        
        //nuget: AspNetCore.HealthChecks.UI
        app.UseHealthChecksUI(options =>
        {
            options.UIPath = "/healthchecks-ui";
            options.ApiPath = "/health-ui-api";
        });
        ...
    }
```

**appsettings.json**

```json
    "HealthChecks-UI": {
        "DisableMigrations": true,
        "HealthChecks": [
            {
                "Name": "PollManager",
                "Uri": "/healthcheck"
            }
        ],
        "Webhooks": [
            {
                "Name": "",
                "Uri": "",
                "Payload": "",
                "RestoredPayload": ""
            }
        ],
        "EvaluationTimeOnSeconds": 10,
        "MinimumSecondsBetweenFailureNotifications": 60,
        "MaximumExecutionHistoriesPerEndpoint": 15
    }
```